# comparing intervals using integers

Tags: c, math, integer, rational-number, fractions

First off, I know there are many different easier/reliable ways to perform what I am about to ask, but that is not the point of my question.

I am attempting to compare two sets of integers as if they were fractions.  What I mean by this is suppose I have a 2d array:

```
int array[2][2];

array[0][0] = 2;
array[0][1] = 3;
array[1][0] = 1;
array[1][1] = 50;
```

How I want to treat these numbers is that the number in:

array[0][0] = 2 <--- is the numerator

array[0][1] = 3 <--- is the denominator

Or just 2/3 in this case.  What I want to do is then compare the two fractions;

```
if(2/3 < 1/50){
  //blah blah blah code here
}
```

The caveat here is that I can not convert the numbers to floating point numbers to retain their accuracy or create a temporary floating point placeholder.  Is there any way to compare these using only integer values?

I also don't know exactly what I should tag for this question, if you think of something let me know and I'll tag it.

Comment: You should change the title to say "rational fractions" rather than "intervals" -- there are no intervals here.

Comment: Interesting question and nicely written. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cross multiply the two numerators by one another's denominators

IE

2/3 vs 1/50th: multiply 50 and 1 by 3 and multiply 2 and 3 by 50.

Then you can compare the numerator without having to convert to a float.

Comment: The example is correct but the wording in the first sentence is not.  Should be "cross multiply the two fractions by one another's denominators".

Comment: very nice, creating a common denominator didn't even cross my mind, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(array[0][0]*array[1][1])<array[0][1]*array[1][0])
{
    // your code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to find the least common multiple, and then convert the numerator. After that you could compare the numerator as integers.

i.e. 2*50 = 100; 1 * 3 = 3; ==> 100 > 3

Comment: Least common multiple? No, you just multiply them.

Comment: For the example asked, I simply multiply them. But the array could be more than 2 rows, it has to given a more generic solution. [2,3][1,50][1,25] ==> [100,150][3,150][6,150], 150 is the least common multiple for 3, 50, 25.